# Python if/else statement in dictionary / dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I'm creating a data frame using a dictionary and I need to use an if else statement within it. I'm not sure how to do this. Do I need to create a logical function to do it?

Also I'm open to recommendations on a better way to create this data frame.

```
`Data1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Name1' : [category.NUMBER1[0]],
                    'Name2' : [category.DATE[0]],
                    'Name3' : [category.NUMBER2[0]],
                    'Name4' : [item],
                    'Name5' :[ if value1 == 'string1' or value2 == 'string2':
                                    [variable1]
                               else: [0]]


                    })`
```

I'm getting invalid syntax for the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
'Name5': [variable1 if value1 == 'string1' or value2 == 'string2' else 0]
```

Your attempt suggests that you want either `[[variable1]]` or `[[0]]`, but I've assumed that what you actually want is either `[variable1]` or `[0]`.